# Stateless (pushState?) back button on ajax forum

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need a stateless way to implement the back button feature in an ajax forum such that if a user is on page 2 of the topics ajax page, and then clicks on the message -  when the user then hits the back button they can go back to the point of the message on the topics ajax page. - your help would be much appreciated.

::Please remember I want a stateless way of doing this, such that it's done client side::

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option you have is to implement a client-side routing mechanism which you can either achieve by changing the `#` in your url whenever you change *state*. For instance your topics page has a url like `yourforum.html#topics` and whenever a user clicks on a message, you redirect (client-side) to `yourforum.html#message/3`.

Your JavaScript code should listen to those hash changes and react accordingly by loading topics/messages.

There 2 ways of client-side routing:

- changing the hash like in the example I made
- HTML5 push-state

Many modern JavaScript frameworks like Backbone, JavaScriptMVC etc... support routing. So you might take a look at those. [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com) might be a good starting point. Otherwise try to google for some jQuery plugins which give you this kind of functionality.

Comment: Thank you - I cannot do this for older browsers?

Comment: I'm not sure about HTML5 push-state, but the hash-method should work without issues and is normally easier in terms of the setup.